# How to clear a text field in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa

I'm trying to make a simple Cocoa application using the newest version of XCode. In interface builder I added NSTextField and NSButton. When I press the button, I want it to clear whatever is in the text field.

I made a new class called AppController.h. This is the contents:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface AppController : NSObject {
    IBOutlet id textView;

}

- (IBAction) clearText: sender;
@end
```

AppController.m looks like this:

```
#import "AppController.h"


@implementation AppController

- (IBAction) clearText: sender 
{ 
    [textView setString: @" "]; 


} 
@end
```

I connected the button to clearText and the textbox to textView.

The program compiles and runs. But when I press the button, nothing happens. Why is that?

Comment: Which version of XCode are you using?

Comment: I'm using the newest one that I downloaded today. Version 3.2.3.

Comment: Future-duping [What's wrong with this Cocoa code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183249/whats-wrong-with-this-cocoa-code), as that newer question seems to have more-focused answers on it.

Answer (score 7):

here's the run down. 
1.Create an IBAction in your appController class header.

```
- (IBAction)someMethod:(id)sender;
```

2.Then create an IBOutlet for you text field

```
 IBOutlet NSTextField *textFieldname;
```

You then connect the IBAction to the button in interface builder, and your IBOutlet to your textfield.

Inside the implementation file (.m) IBAction method do

```
- (IBAction)someMethod:(id)sender{
 textFieldname.stringValue = @"";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very basic. I suggest you google for some tutorials. There's plenty out there. Here's something that may help. Chapter 8 describes how to do exactly what you're asking.
[link text](http://cocoalab.com/?q=becomeanxcoder)

Comment: I tried following that tutorial, but I can't because it looks like it was made for an older version of Xcode.

Comment: If you can't follow that tutorial then do as I suggested and google for other tutorials. I'm sure you'll find something you like.

Comment: That's what I've been doing. All the tutorials I find are for older versions of xcode. What I was trying to do also comes from such a tutorial.